# how to get the previous page url in AccessDeniedHandle

Tags: java, spring

i'm using "SPRING MVC" and i would like to redirect users to the previous page when they get the error "Access Denied" so i created an implement from "AccessDeniedHandle"

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf1LQ.jpg)

my problem is how can i get the previous page link ? or should i use a controller ?
any suggestion please ?

Comment: Please visit [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question needs a lot of editing.

Comment: hope it's clear now @rmlan

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution using controller, but if you think you have a better suggestion please share it

**spring-security.xml**

```
<security:http...>
     ...
     <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
     ...
</security:http...>
```

**myController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/403", method=RequestMethod.GET)
         public void accessDenied(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Authentication auth) {
          String previousPage = (String) session.getAttribute("previousPage"); 
            if(previousPage.isEmpty())
            {
                if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN"))
                {
                  try {
                    response.sendRedirect("olx/index");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                else if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER"))
                {
                  try {
                    response.sendRedirect("me/index");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    response.sendRedirect(previousPage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }
```

**in every jsp**

```
<% Object thisPage = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
session.setAttribute("previousPage",thisPage); %>
```